# In Oracle, how to loop round all_tables joining using table_name

Tags: oracle, loops, tablename

I have a bunch of tables which each have a `LOADED_TIMESTAMP` column. I want to use `ALL_TABLE.TABLE_NAME` to get the `MAX(LOADED_TIMESTAMP)` from all 'F_' tables, so that the query result is e.g.

```
tablename1   2018-05-10 17:33

tablename2   2018-05-04 00:13

tablename3   2018-03-23 08:44
...
```

I want to use `ALL_TABLES` to do this so that if any new tables get added, they will automatically be included.
I plan to use this to write the results to a table daily, so I have a history of when each table was loaded each day

I've googled / searched Stack Overflow but am just getting errors (or 'PL/SQL procedure successfully completed' but no results!) when I try executing the code in SQL Developer...

Starting to go round in circles; Any help would be much appreciated.
Here's the SQL I've got at the moment.

```
DECLARE 
  my_sql VARCHAR(1000); 
BEGIN 
  FOR t IN 
  ( 
         SELECT t.table_name, 
                t.owner 
         FROM   all_tables t 
         WHERE  owner = 'ME' 
         AND    Substr(t.table_name,1,2) IN ('A_', 
                                             'F_' , 
                                             'P_') ) 
  LOOP 
    my_sql := 'select max(dw_loaded_timestamp) as last_loaded from ' 
    || t.owner 
    || '.' 
    || t.table_name ; 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE my_sql; 
  END LOOP; 
EXCEPTION 
WHEN OTHERS THEN 
  dbms_output.Put_line('ERROR!! -- ' 
  || SQLCODE 
  || '-- ' 
  || SQLERRM 
  || ' --' ); 
END;
/
```

Comment: Is this an activity that will be automated or manual?  if manaul and infrequent simply write a query that writes out the SQL necessary to get those values and then execute the results.

Comment: Can you show your code? Hint: a simple dynamic SQL does the job. Iterate through `all_tables` and use 'execute immediate ... with out' to calculate max for each table.

Comment: This is something I want to be doing on a daily basis, so I want to automate it & put it in a stored procedure or view ...

Comment: Here's the SQL I've got at the moment. 

    DECLARE
    my_sql VARCHAR(1000);
    BEGIN
         FOR t IN (SELECT t.table_name, t.owner FROM all_tables t where owner = 'ME' and substr(t.table_name,1,2) in ('A_','F_' ,'P_')  )
         LOOP
         my_sql := 'select max(dw_loaded_timestamp) as last_loaded from ' || t.owner || '.' || t.table_name ;
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE my_sql;
         END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('ERROR!! -- ' || SQLCODE || '-- ' || sqlerrm || ' --' );
    END;
    /

Comment: I modified slightly and think this will give the results you are looking for:
DECLARE 
    my_sql VARCHAR(1000); 
    my_val int;
BEGIN 

    FOR t IN (SELECT t.table_name, t.owner FROM all_tables t where owner = 'ME' and substr(t.table_name,1,2) in ('A_','F_' ,'P_') ) 
LOOP my_sql := 'select max(dw_loaded_timestamp) as last_loaded from ' || t.owner || '.' || t.table_name ;  
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE my_sql into my_val; 
    dbms_output.put_line(my_val);
END LOOP; 
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN dbms_output.put_line('ERROR!! -- ' || SQLCODE || '-- ' || sqlerrm || ' --' ); 
END; 
/

Comment: Just read that you are going to redirect output to a table.   Nothing in your code to do that, so I'm guessing you wanted to check the output of the SQL first.  My modifications will allow you to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume this is a one time thing...  We can use SQL to write SQL and then execute the result set after a quick removal of the last union all..

```
SELECT 'SELECT max(LOADED_TIMESTAMP) as maxLoadedTimeStamp, ' 
       || chr(39) || TABLE_NAME || chr(39) || ' as srcTable '
       || 'FROM '|| table_Name || ' UNION ALL '
FROM all_tables 
WHERE owner = 'yourSchemaOwner' 
  and table_Name like 'F/_%';
```

Then copy/paste the results and remove the last UNION ALL from the last statement and execute it.  In the above the / before the _ is to escape it; otherwise it's just "any character" when I presume you mean tables are named 'F_XXXX'
YourschmeaOwner is just so we limit the query your your schema.

Giving us something like...

```
SELECT max(LOADED_TIMESTAMP) as maxLoadedTimeStamp, 'F_xxx0' as srcTable FROM F_xxx0 UNION ALL 
SELECT max(LOADED_TIMESTAMP) as maxLoadedTimeStamp, 'F_xxx1' as srcTable FROM F_xxx1 UNION ALL 
SELECT max(LOADED_TIMESTAMP) as maxLoadedTimeStamp, 'F_xxx2' as srcTable FROM F_xxx2
```

and then your results would be:

```
F_xxx1 2018-05-10 17:33
F_xxx2 2018-05-04 00:13
F_xxx3 2018-03-23 08:44 ...
```

If not; do the above via Dynamic SQL and execute it in a procedure.

Comment: It's not a one-time thing so "do the above via Dynamic SQL and execute it in a procedure" is what I'm hoping someone can help with !